# Magento save and retrieve data from multiple tables and models in my custom module

Tags: magento-1.7

In Magento how can we save and retrieve data from multiple tables and models in my custom module.

Comment: you have to give more details on this. Like what are you trying to achieve, or a simple example of what you need.

Comment: I want to create two or more tables from same module then perform join actions on them in my collection.